# Remoting into Raspberry Pi 4 using VNC viewer without permission

Tags: pi-4, ubuntu, vnc

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu 20.04 and every time I try to remote in, it prompts this message:

> Another user is trying to view your desktop. A user on the computer "192.bla.blah.blah" is trying to remotely view your computer...

I would just like to remote in without going to my raspberry pi and clicking yes every single time. Is there a way to do this? I am using VNCviewer to access the display from my windows laptop using the VNC client.

Comment: So, what is on 192.168.blah.blah?

Comment: 192.168.blah.blah is just my windows laptop trying to remote in

Comment: Your windows client keeps the session open. The can happen if you just stop viewing the session (close the viewing window) instead of logging out. I'm not much use for the windows side though, sorry.